# Как убрать цифру в числе на python? (первую и последнюю)

Tags: python

Я бы хотел узнать, как убрать первую и последнюю цифры в числе.

Пример: У меня есть массив чисел, и если какой-то элемент <=99, то заменить на 0.

**Ввод:** [135,12,7399,45]

**Вывод:** [3,0,39,0]

Comment: OUT = [int(str(i)[1:-1]) if i>99 else 0 for i in INT]

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:**

```
inp = [135,12,7399,45]
out = []
for i in inp:
    if i <= 99:
        out.append(0)
    else:
        out.append(int(str(i)[1:-1])) 
print(out)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Зачем второй список, если можно изменять элементы этого?